# Date format in excel with apache poi

Tags: java, excel, date, formatting, apache-poi

I use apache poi to write excel file with java. What I need is a way to use "directly" [this](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Format-a-date-the-way-you-want-8e10019e-d5d8-47a1-ba95-db95123d273e?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US) format codes to format dates when writing Date variables in some excel cell, eg. something like "dddd dd/mm/yyyy".
The BuiltInFormats doesn't seem a complete collection of what I need.
I think an optimal solution would use a carefully set instance of XSSFCellStyle to achieve the goal.

Comment: you can define your own data format as a short with oyu can set as xssfcellstyle

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had to do this recently. Check out the following example. I'm sure it will be quite similar when using XSSF instead.

```
    CreationHelper creationHelper = hssfWorkbook.getCreationHelper();
    cellStyle.setDataFormat(creationHelper.createDataFormat().getFormat(("dd.MM.yyyy")));
    HSSFCell c1 = hssfRow.createCell(0);
    HSSFCellUtil.setCellStyleProperty(c1, hssfWorkbook, CellUtil.DATA_FORMAT,
            HSSFDataFormat.getBuiltinFormat(("dd.MM.yyyy")));
    c1.setCellStyle(cellStyle);
    c1.setCellValue(HSSFDateUtil.getExcelDate(new java.util.Date()));
```

Answer (score 2):

I solved by using this (workbook and cell were already defined as XSSFWorkbook and XSSFCell):

```
CreationHelper creationHelper = workbook.getCreationHelper();
CellStyle cellStyle = workbook.createCellStyle();
cellStyle.setDataFormat(creationHelper.createDataFormat().getFormat("dddd dd/mm/yyyy"));
cell.setCellStyle(cellStyle);
```